# Using AngularJS to store user input in an array while incrementing said array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, input, storage

I'm creating a debit/credit calculator using AngularJS to familiarize myself with AngularJS. I'm trying to store user input in an array that I can then show in a table underneath the input.

I would like the user to enter a debit, credit, date, and purpose for a particular day and the store each one of those inputs in an individual array. So the first input would ideally be stored in:

```
debit[0];
credit[0];
date[0];
purpose[0];
```

Then the user would save the data for that day and be able to enter all new data while storing the previous data in the table underneath.

I thought I could increment each array one time in order to store all the data in the same index in each array and then call that specific index each row of the table.

```
    <div ng-app="">

    <table>

        <tr>
            <th>
                <p>Input a debit:</p>
                <input type="number" ng-model="debit">
            </th>
            <th>
                <p>Input a credit:</p>
                <input type="number" ng-model="credit">
            </th>

            <th>
                <p>Date:</p>
                <input type="text" ng-model="date">
            </th>

            <th>
                <p>Purpose:</p>
                <input type="text" ng-model="purpose">
            </th>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <table>

        <tr>
            <th>
                <p>Debit</p>
                <p></p>
                <p id="debit"></p>
            </th>
            <th>
                <p>Credit</p>
                <p>{{ credit }}</p>
            </th>
            <th>
                <p>Date</p>
                <p>{{ date }}</p>
            </th>
            <th>
                <p>Purpose</p>
                <p>{{ purpose }}</p>
            </th>
            <th>
                <p>Balance</p>
                    <div ng-app="">
                        <p>{{ debit - credit }}</p>
                    </div>
            </th>
        </tr>

    </table>

</div>

    <script>
        var debitArray = [];
        document.getElementById("debit").innerHTML = debitArray;
    </script>
```

Comment: Why the separate arrays? Wouldn't one array that held an JSON object for each set of data be easier?

Comment: Mainly because I'm new to all this and didn't know that would be better hahah. Decided it would be easier in just plain old JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

What about using an object to store all information of a specific user with a day property as an array of objects that will store all the information:

```
let obj = {
    userId: 1,
    userName: "John",
    userEmail: "john@john.com",
    day: [
            {
            debit: [
                [valueForArrayOfDay0],
                [valueForArrayOfDay0]
            ],
            credit: [],
            date: [],
            purpose: []
            },
            {
            debit: [
                [valueForArrayOfDay1],
                [valueForArrayOfDay1]
            ],
            credit: [],
            date: [],
            purpose: []
            }
        ]
};
```

If you **console.log(obj.day[0])** you would have this object as a result:

```
{ 
    debit: [ [ 'valueForArrayOfDay0' ], [ 'valueForArrayOfDay0' ] ],
    credit: [],
    date: [],
    purpose: [] 
}
```